# Rails 4 has_many association form not building

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nested-attributes, has-many

Maybe I still do not understand how Rails 4 works with has_many and belongs_to association.

My form doesn't save the has_many relationship

Entry Model

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :survey
    has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

Answer Model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :entry
    validates :content, presence: true
    validates :entry_id, presence: true
end
```

Entry Controller

```
def create
    @answer = Entry.create(params.require(:entry).permit(:survey_id, answers_attributes [:content, :entry_id]))
    redirect_to '/'
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for(:entry, :url => {:controller => 'entrys', :action => 'create'}) do |q| %>
    <%= q.hidden_field :survey_id, :value => @survey.id %>
    <%= q.fields_for :answer do |a| %>
        <%= a.text_field :content %>
    <% end %>
    <%= q.submit :Save %>
<% end %>
```

Debug error

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"**********************=", "entry"=>{"survey_id"=>"1", "answer"=>{"content"=>"asdasd"}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
Unpermitted parameters: answer
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `fields_for` in your form as below:

```
   <%= q.fields_for :answers do |a| %>
        <%= a.text_field :content %>
    <% end %>
```

Note pluralized `:answers` and not `:answer`.
As `Entry` model is associated to `Answer` in a 1-M Relationship, you should be using plural `:answers` in fields for.

Right now as you used `:answer` (singular), it wasn't interpreted by rails correctly, so you received `answer` key in `params` hash instead of receiving `answers_attributes` which obviously resulted in warning as `Unpermitted parameters: answer`

**UPDATE**

Update the `create` action as below:

```
def create
    @answer = Entry.create(params.require(:entry).permit(:survey_id, answers_attributes: [:content, :entry_id]))
    redirect_to '/'
end
```

It should be `answers_attributes: [:content, :entry_id]` and not `answers_attributes [:content, :entry_id]` (Notice missing `:`)

Also, I would suggest you to update your Entry Controller `new` action as below:

```
def new
  @entry = Entry.new
  @entry.answers.build
end
```

After this update the `form_for` as below:

```
<%= form_for(@entry) do |q| %>
```

**NOTE:**

The controller name is not as per Rails convention so it is messing up the `params` hash. Instead of getting `entry` as a key, you are getting `entrie`. I would recommend changing the controller name `EntrysController` to `EntriesController`. Renaming the file `entrys_controller.rb` to `entries_controller.rb`. Also, update the routes specific to this controller in `routes.rb` by replacing all occurrences of `entrys` with `entries`

Comment: Kirti, thanks for your answes. By pluralizing :answers the only difference is that instead of "Unpermitted parameters: answer" in the error message now it says "Unpermitted parameters: answers".

Comment: kirti I already did what you suggested me, I updated the form_for to "@entry" and in the controller I defined "@entry" as you suggested me.
This is what happens:
When I leave everything as you told me neither entry nor answer is submitted.
But when I remove "@entry.answers.build" just entry is submitted.

Comment: The console displays this when I leave everything just as you suggested:
`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PlJA6FxSyDCdeqqLmrSM7P8xmKeYIbA3HFLQ18D8Xqo=", "entrie"=>{"survey_id"=>"1", "answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"asdasdasdasd"}}}, "commit"=>"Actualizar"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction`